# Android Studio generated files in java folder after upgrading to AGP 8 + Gradle 8.0 + Kotlin 1.8.20

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, kapt

The problem is exactly as said in the title. Android Studio is putting Hilt and Glide generated files in regular java folder instead of java(generated) leading to a lot of generated files and packages next to source files.

Problem occurs only on 1.8 Kotlin version. Everything prior to this version works fine. I believe that the root of the problem is kapt, using annotationProcessor leads to the expected result

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to be easier to help you

Comment: No any issues here about this specific problem. So I think you need to provide an example.....

Comment: I think this issue has been fixed in the recent version of Android Studio, I too had this issue but with the new studio I just cleaned and rebuilt the project and that seems to have solved this issue.

For reference this is my studio version *Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1*, other setting have been left the same

Answer (score 2):

Go to the Android Studio Settings and open this path like so:

```
Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools > Gradle
```

[image]

Change the `Gradle JDK` to the `11` version if it is `17` and press OK.
Roll back any changes in files that define the JDK version like misc.xml.

Clean your project using `Build` menu in the toolbar and `Clean Project` item and rebuild your project. It is also a good idea to `Invalidate Caches` and restart before build.

Comment: This is not a full fix to this problem but an answer in a right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Didn't work at all, seems that the issue is with kapt

Comment: Yep, this is surely a kapt issue. @ibrhm117 is right. The problem might go away if you consider switching to ksp. But unfortunately KSP is not yet ready for all production purposes. Mainly, dagger is yet to implement KSP support.

Comment: @IlyaZagarovsky you're right, but KSP has issues of its own and would just become too much of a hassle to deal with